# hiphop-php error during compiling a cakephp application

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to compile my CakePHP application through Hiphop.

After Installation Steps I Followed.

```
cd /root/hiphop/
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`pwd`/local
cd /root/hiphop/hiphop-php
export HPHP_HOME=`pwd`
export HPHP_LIB=`pwd`/bin
$HPHP_HOME/src/hphp/hphp test.php --keep-tempdir=1 --log=3
/tmp/path of the program -m server -p 80
```

and the above steps worked for me. 
When I am trying to compile my CakePHP Application it's giving an error like below.

```
/tmp/hphp_AWLsty/php/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.cpp: In static member function 'static HPHP::Variant HPHP::c_CakeTime::t_listtimezones(HPHP::Variant, const HPHP::Variant&, const HPHP::Variant&)':\n/tmp/hphp_AWLsty/php/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.cpp:2519: error: 'q_DateTimeZone___ALL' was not declared in this scope\nmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/program.dir/php/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.cpp.o] Error 1\nmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/program.dir/all] Error 2\nmake: *** [all] Error 2\n
compiling and linking CPP files took 11'59" (719602 ms) wall time
hphp failed
running hphp took 12'06" (726606 ms) wall time
```

Refereed the link to compile the CakePHP application. http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2012/01/30/running_cakephp_using_the_facebooks_hiphop_compiler